# How do I print my output from left to right?

Tags: c#

Below codes run perfectly fine. But how to I print converted number in left to right manner. For example if I input 898989, it will give me the output DB7AD. How do I print

- `DB7AD`  to

  ```
  D 

     B

        7

            A

               D
  ```

  Codes:

  ```
  public static void Main()
  {
      int decimalNumber, quotient;
      int i = 1, j, num = 0;
      char [] hexadecimalNumber = new char[100];
      char temp;
      Console.WriteLine("Decimal to HexaDecimal conversion using Ascii code.\n");
      Console.WriteLine("Input DECIMAL NUMBER(S) you want to convert to      HEXADECIMAL(S):\t\n");
      Console.Write("Decimal Numbers : \t");

      decimalNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      quotient = decimalNumber;
      while (quotient != 0)
      {
          num = quotient % 16;
          if (num < 10)
              num = num + 48;
          else
              num = num + 55;
          temp = Convert.ToChar(num);
          hexadecimalNumber[i++] = temp;
          quotient = quotient / 16;
      }

      Console.Write("HexaDecimal Numbers : \t");

      for (j = i - 1; j > 0; j--)
      Console.Write(hexadecimalNumber[j]);
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.Read();

  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are printing your number character-by-character, you need to modify this loop

```
for (j = i - 1; j > 0; j--) {
    Console.Write(hexadecimalNumber[j]);
}
```

in such a way as to print zero tabs before the first digit, one tab before the second digit, two tabs before the third digit, and so on. You can do it by making a `string tabs` variable, and adding a `"\t"` to it after each iteration:

```
string tabs = "";
for (j = i - 1; j > 0; j--) {
    Console.WriteLine(tabs + hexadecimalNumber[j]);
    tabs += "\t";
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/FjX3qN)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You made it seems pretty easy. I was overthinking it. Thank you again.